# How does this code return 2^4 power?

Tags: javascript

```
`var result = 1;
for (var counter = 0; counter < 4; counter = counter + 1)
  result = result * 2;
console.log(result);
// → 16`
```

Where does the new value for result come from?

Comment: if result is 1...  `1*2=2 ... 2*2=4 ... 4*2=8 ... 8*2=16`.  Each loop redefines the value of `result` to `result * 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's simple enough

There is one

```
result = 1
```

In loop it will be

```
result = result * 2; //result is 2
result = result * 2; //result is 4
result = result * 2; //result is 8
result = result * 2; //result is 16
```

Which is same as `2^4`.

Comment: What would the value be if counter < 6; counter = counter + 2?

Comment: asking doesn't help, why not try?

Answer (score 1):

First loop through `result = 1 * 2`

second loop through `result = 2(result from first) * 2`

third time through `result = 4(result from second) * 2`

and last time through result = `8(result from third) * 2`

Loop only goes through 4 times, and that's how you get `2^4`